# Mongoose: How can I access a populated field from a virtual getter?

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mongoose-schema, mongoose-populate

I have a couple Schemas:

```
var parentSchema = new Schema({name: String});
var childSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    parent: {type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Parent'}
});
```

I want to be able to call `Child.find().populate('parent')` and then use the following virtual getter:

```
childSchema.virtual('url').get(function () {
    return "/" + this.parent.name + "/" + this.name
});
```

However, when I call the `find().populate()` and then pass the resulting child to my view, and attempt to use `child.url`, I always get `parent.name` set to undefined. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I know it's an old question but you can try something like:

```
childSchema.virtual('url').get(function () {
    this.populate("parent");
    return "/" + this.parent.name + "/" + this.name
});
```

It's mentioned [here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#populate-middleware) in the official documentation.